# Will running games like hayday or clash of clans in the background for a very long time consume battery?

Tags: iphone

I noticed that I often open 4 games at once. Hay day, clash of clans, infinity blade, and boom beach.

I wonder if I should terminate those apps when I no longer use it?

If i keep it on will it consume battery>

Answer (score 1):

In iOS if an app does not do background processing it does not take up battery. Games should not be doing background processing.

When you get low on memory iOS will send a signal to all apps so that they can reduce their memory usage and some will free memory. If there is still not enough memory for the current app iOS will terminate other apps.

Thus iOS will terminate apps for you - you do not need to terminate them manually and there is no benefit in doing so.

So leave the apps alone..

Of course if an app is badly written and does background things then terminating might be needed but this is unusual and the developer has to do this deliberately so I thin k games should definitely be OK - there are some apps that look at your location which do misbehave but hames don't need this.

Answer (score 0):

Your natural instinct on an iPhone is to always open your multi-tasking and to close apps to conserve battery. This actually can poorly affect your battery. Memory in a phone and memory in a computer do not really work the same way.

iOS uses memory to quickly open applications from memory. When you constantly close apps from multi-tasking and reopening them you are putting much more strain on the RAM by constantly removing all the application memory and re-writing it to RAM everytime you open it.

Best practice for iOS in my case has been to never close an app from multi-tasking unless it crashes or is frozen.

If an application is draining a lot of battery then remove the game or submit the issue to the game developers to fix it, but some games are very graphic intense and can cause battery drain issues. No game will run beautifully with maximum graphics and not put at least some strain on the battery.

Comment: For the life of me, I don't know why this answer was downvoted. It may be a generic answer but the question isn't terribly specific itself!